# Monitoring file changes in C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, file-monitoring

I am working with Linux, and I have a directory which has subdirectories and there are files inside subdirectories.

I have to monitor the changes in the file. In C++ I am using [Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_%28C%2B%2B_libraries%29). I go through all the directories every 30 seconds and check the *last_write_time*. Principally, it works. But every time this action is executed, my CPU goes nuts and I see 15%-25% CPU usage
just for this program in top. I have read about *[inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify)*. If I use *inotify*, would I have the more or less same CPU usage or would it be improved? Is there a good alternative to what I am doing?

Comment: The performance will be vastly improved, as you would not have to go through all files and sub-directories. Instead you will get a notification when a file or directory has changed. Inotify is probably the best way to go on Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the input Joachim. I am gonna try that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you use inotify, you do not require to poll for all files to check if there are changes. You get a callback system that notifies you when a watched file or directory got changed.

The kernel/filesystem already has this information, so the resource/CPU usage is not just moved to another application, it is actually reduced.

[Monitor file system activity with inotify](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-ubuntu-inotify/) provides more details why to use inotify, shows its basic usage and helps you set it up.